# Deploy Maven project on cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I have a Jenkin job configured in Cloudbees for which source is from bit bucket repository. I have a java spring security app stored in the repository. Its a maven project with pom.xml. But I do not have any .war file in the source. So how do I deploy this on Cloudbees. All the options need .war file existing with the source code. Is it possible to create .war on bitbucket or cloudbees during build or deployment. 
Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The .war file is never auto-generated, you have to create it. You can do it for example from your laptop launching the "mvn clean package" command once you are inside the folder which contains the pom.xml file.

From the IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, ..) there is usually an option to generate it. Once you have the .war file, you can deploy it via CloudBees SDK. [Here](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/bind-your-java-application-to-your.html), there is an example which explains how to do it step by step for a Tomcat 7 app.

However, you can also deploy from Jenkins directly through the "Post-build Actions->Deploy applications" option. Jenkins will automatically generate the .war file and will deploy to the instance you say. You should create the app before specifying where you want to deploy it.

Comment: Yes , I am using "Post-build Actions->Deploy applications" . For Jenkin to generate war file for my Maven app. These are my settings.

Comment: Butthe build fails. Following is console output :

Comment: [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,

Comment: Please, launch the Tomcat 7 ClickStart(https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-maven-clickstart) and copy the configuration for your project. It should be the same one.